# Username and Password validation to list

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am very new to web development and am attempting to write code to validate username and password combinations. http://universe.tc.uvu.edu/cs2550/assignments/PasswordCheck/check.php is the link to run the check, and http://universe.tc.uvu.edu/cs2550/assignments/PasswordCheck/list.php is the list of acceptable entries. I am able to hard code in a username and password and that seems to be working fine, my question is simply "How can I hook up this input, to check inside the server for an acceptable login." Thank you for your help in advance!

Here is my form:

```
<form id = "formLogin" method = "post" name = "myform">
<label>User Name: </label>
<input type = "text" name = "username" id = "username" />
<label>Password: </label>
<input type = "password" name = "password" id = "password">
<input type = "button" value = "Login" id = "submit" onclick = "validate()">
<input type = "reset" value = "Reset">
</form>
```

Here is my javascript thus far:

```
function validate(){
var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
if(username == ""){
    alert("Please enter a User Name")
    formLogin.username.focus()
    return false
}
if(password == ""){
    alert("Please enter a Password")
    formLogin.password.focus()
    return false
}
if( username == "Test" && password == "test#123"){
    alert("Login successfully");
    window.location = "gameboard.html";
    return false;
}
else{
 alert("Login failed - Please enter correct Username and Password")   
}
}
```

Comment: You have to submit the form the server (you form should have an "action" attribute pointing to a url from your server), than the server gets the parameters and validate them. Remove this javascript that checks the inputs.

Comment: I think he wants to be able to validate using AJAX

Comment: This is fine for learning, but note that this is *not* fine for production code. You don't check a password against a list, you never store the password, only a hash and a salt that you check against.

Comment: Also note that validation in JavaScript is bad because users can disable JavaScript and there goes your validation. Validation needs to be handled server side.

Comment: I would add to @SythnetP and say that you need to validate on both the client and server side. There is nothing more annoying then filling in a form and leaving something out by mistake and then having to fill it in again when the slip up could have been avoided.

Comment: You comments are all making a lot of sense. I am just trying to get a grip on this set list of acceptable users and passwords. Security not being my main focus, until another time.

Comment: Ignore the people blindly telling you to use jQuery. It might be great, but you definitely don't need a full library just to do AJAX. A 5-line bit of JS will suffice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try looking into [jQuery's AJAX function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Upon submission of the login form, send the username and password combo to http://universe.tc.uvu.edu/cs2550/assignments/PasswordCheck/check.php as follows.

```
<form id="formLogin" method="post" name="myform">
   <label>User Name:</label>
   <input type="text" name="username" id="username">

   <label>Password:</label>
   <input type="password" name="password" id="password">

   <input type="submit" value="Login" id="submit">
   <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#formLogin').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var username = $('input#username').val();
    var password = $('input#password').val();

    if(password == ""){
       alert("Please enter a Password");
       $('#password').focus();
       return false;
    }

    if(username == ""){
       alert("Please enter a Username");
       $('#username').focus();
       return false;
    }

    if(username != '' && password != '') {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://universe.tc.uvu.edu/cs2550/assignments/PasswordCheck/check.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                username: username,
                password: password
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                // It looks like the page that handles the form returns JSON
                // Parse the JSON
                var obj = JSON.parse(data);

                if(obj.result != 'invalid') {
                    alert("Login succeeded");
                    // You should redirect the user too
                    window.location = 'http://redirecturl.com';
                }                    
            }
        });
    } 
}); 
</script>
```

This effectively validates your form submission. I prefer using the jQuery library as opposed to raw JS. You should look into it too.

It's also worth noting that forms must ALWAYS be validated on the server side as well. Because a client could always just disable JavaScript in their browser to bypass your front end validation. As mentioned by someone who commented on your question, your method of backend validation is pretty insecure. Raw values of passwords should never be stored. Rather, it's good to use an [sha1 hash](http://php.net/sha1) of the password so that if an unwanted user somehow hacks into your DB he/she doesn't have all of the passwords stored in there.

Also, username/password combination validation works a lot smoother on the backend if you just do something like

```
// Connect to the DB
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db'); 
// Escape the form values or user prepared statements
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $username);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $password);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$username." AND password = '".$password."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($count == 1) {
    echo "Success";
} else {
    echo "Fail";
}
```

instead of using a static list.

Comment: How to I get this to work with my HTML code? As I had it above, it was just  running the onclick validate function

Comment: So when I run this code, I am able to enter text into the username and password fields but when I click my button to Login it isn't doing anything

Comment: Sorry. The button in your form needed the `type` attribute set to `submit` instead of `button`. Try it now.

Comment: Lance I appreciate you working this out with me, I still cannot get the Login button to successfully log me in. The blank text checkers work when I click login but it doesn't redirect me

Comment: Have you checked your JavaScript console?

Comment: Yes sir, it gives me {"result" : "invalid"}, no matter what is entered into the fields

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here -

1. You can use a server side language like ASP.Net / PHP and you can add an action attribute to your form,

This will then submit to the validate.php passing in any controls with a name tag to the validate.php page.

```
<form name='something' method='POST' action='validate.php'>
<label>User Name: </label>
<input type = "text" name = "username" id = "username" />
<label>Password: </label>
<input type = "password" name = "password" id = "password">   
<input type = "submit" value = "Login" id = "submit"">
<input type = "reset" value = "Reset">
</form>
```

I would suggest you learn a server side language for this, I'm not going to post the code, I will leave that to you to learn.

OR

2. You can use JQuery (Don't have too, but it's easier in my opinion) to call an AJAX request to the server to validate.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Good examples on how to use JQuery and AJAX to call some server side code.

Answer (score 0):

Checking pass in js doesnt make sense, because user can see js code. Use PHP and AJAX.